# What username/password/signature should I be using for the PayPal Sandbox?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to refund transactions using the Paypal NVP API.  I've got some payments in a sandbox account, but when I try to issue a refund though the API I get `You do not have permissions to make this API call`.  But I'm not sure what credentials I should be using.

According to [the documentation](https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_NVPAPI_DeveloperGuide/overview.html), it says:

> To access the PayPal API, you need API credentials, either an API
>   signature or API certificate, that identify you.  Use the following
>   sample API signature and password in your sample programs that run in
>   the PayPal Sandbox test environment.
>
> `API username sdk-three_api1.sdk.com`
>   `API password QFZCWN5HZM8VBG7Q`
>   `API signature A‑IzJhZZjhg29XQ2qnhapuwxIDzyAZQ92FRP5dqBzVesOkzbdUONzmOU`

I tried generating API credentials for the sandbox merchant account that's issuing the refunds, but the Paypal website crashes every time I try.  Are these the correct credentials?  What do I need to do to test this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your test accounts do not have credentials.

To get started with Payment Card in Sandbox, you must first create a buyer test account and enable in-store checkout.

After login sandbox you will find that option in menu **API and Payment Card Credentials**
and then click it you will get option **Create Test Account** and after create account you will get API Username, API Password and Signature.

Use those API Username, API Password and Signature in your application.

Comment: You'd have to view the settings for created Business Account to get the Username, password and signature. Personal account will not have those details.

Comment: or you can follow this step
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npSiN4h-cCQ

Answer (score 3):

I found these details in my account after logging in:

go to the **sandbox** tab

below this you will find **Accounts**. Click on **Accounts**.

All your email lists will be shown.

Click on the email id that belongs to the Business account.

You will see two options: **profile** and **notifications** below the email id's.

After clicking on **profile** one window will pop up with name **Account details**.

In that you will see the tab **API Credentials**. In this you will find your username, password and signature. Please note : You will find these details only in your Business type account, not for buyer type.