# PLATFORM Application Error Application Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect. in Paypal Adaptive Payment

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

In Paypal Adaptive Payment returning the error "PLATFORM Application Error Application Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect." After changing my server.

Please reply if anybody know the solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your API credentials are wrong. Or you're pointing to a Sandbox endpoint with Live credentials or vice versa.
There's no other reason.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on the answer above.

You can check that you are using the right credentials. If you are using the sandbox for development check this guys answer: [What username/password/signature should I be using for the PayPal Sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033940/what-username-password-signature-should-i-be-using-for-the-paypal-sandbox)

Otherwise, you should use the credentials for your production paypal account. You need to request those from paypal (not developer.paypal just normal paypal.com) This should help: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECAPICredentials/

I went around in circles until I found the application credentials on my xxxfacilitator@xxx sandbox test account.