# PHP - PayPal Parallel Payments Error

Tags: php, paypal

I'm trying to implement PayPal Parallel Payments on my website, that manages transactions between end-users and a bus company that is chosen by the end-user. During the process, a 10% of the whole amount should be given to my company, and the rest to the bus company. This is my PHP code (I will delete some parts that are not relevant to the question):

```
$compMail = [...];
$amount = [...];
$myAmount = ($amount * 10) / 100;
$amountCompany = $amount - $myAmount;

$API_Endpoint = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$credentials = array(
'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: '. "sdk-three_api1.sdk.com",
'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: '. "xxxx",
'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: '. "A‑xxxxx",
'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV',
'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV',
'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: '. "APP-XXX"
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $credentials);

$detail_level = urlencode("ReturnAll");
$error_language = urlencode("it_IT");

$nvp_req = "actionType=PAY&clientDetails.applicationId=APP-80W284485P519543T&clientDetails.ipAddress=127.0.0.1&currencyCode=EUR&feesPayer=EACHRECEIVER&memo=Example&receiverList.receiver(0).amount=$amountCompany&receiverList.receiver(0).email=$compMail&receiverList.receiver(0).primary=true&receiverList.receiver(1).amount=$myAmount&receiverList.receiver(1).email=bitleapps@gmail.com&receiverList.receiver(1).primary=false&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=it_IT&returnUrl=[...]&cancelUrl=[...]";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvp_req);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $response;
```

But when this code is executed, this is the response:

```
responseEnvelope.timestamp=2015-07-12T04%3A55%3A28.308-07%3A00&responseEnvelope.ack=Failure&responseEnvelope.correlationId=b33b7d0d86ca3&responseEnvelope.build=17325060&error(0).errorId=520002&error(0).domain=PLATFORM&error(0).subdomain=Application&error(0).severity=Error&error(0).category=Application&error(0).message=Internal+Error&error(0).parameter(0)=Client+exception%2C+while+calling+AuthAndAuth.authenticate_and_authorize+1.1%3A
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Reset your paypal api credentials to start with.

Comment: What do you exactly mean and how do I do that? I'm kinda new to PayPal API...

Comment: You just pasted your api credentials on here; to prevent usage of that by unauthorised people, change your credentials.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31367660/2 You've told everyone your credentials.

Comment: Those weren't my real credentials. I found these credentials here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033940 and I thought that they were sample credentials I could use for any sandbox application. I wouldn't have posted them in any other case.

Comment: Please answer my question.

Comment: That's most likely your problem.  You need to generate your own sandbox credentials from your own developer account, and setup other sandbox accounts to use as the receivers on the payment.

Comment: You generate your own credentials by going to developer.paypal.com and logging in. Then you will go to dashboard and sandbox accounts on the left.

Comment: I had to do something similar. Read [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-parallelPayment-curl-etc/) and [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) and be sure to understand it right. 
Then check that you are connecting to PP from the right host with the test credentials. Be sure to use the general develop app id.
If nothing helps you can contact the pp team which is helpful when it comes to problems like this.